# Can't find bug causing "active assertions beyond permitted time" crash

Tags: iphone, ios, crash, assertions

I am getting the following crash log that shows my app has "active assertions beyond permitted time".  My app is an audio streaming app.  The crash only occurs when the app is in the background and NOT streaming any audio content.

NOTES:

- I ensured that beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler in applicationDidEnterBackground has a corresponding endBackgroundTask in applicationWillEnterForeground.
- All network accesses are on their own thread and not on the main thread.
- When the app is in the background there is no attempt by any thread to access the network.
- The error is random and cannot be duplicated by switching device to airplane mode or turning off WiFi.

Any suggestions for how to track this down?

Here is the crash log (without binary images):

```
Incident Identifier: 0467A340-1FD2-4D49-9FA4-76360889976D
CrashReporter Key:   fdae46f133d13bdc3f043301bc008bd56155588d
Hardware Model:      iPhone3,1
Process:         MyApp [249]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/DAA6B446-07D3-4C7C-BD44-80920338CAF4/MyApp/MyApp
Identifier:      MyApp
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-17 15:25:59.960 -0500
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x8badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  4

Application Specific Information:
MyApp[249] has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <SBProcessAssertion: 0xfed8890> identifier: UIKitBackgroundCompletionTask process: MyApp[249] permittedBackgroundDuration: 600.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:249 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep 
)}

Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 10.700 (user 10.700, system 0.000), 2% CPU 
Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.024, 0% CPU

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f010 0x3630e000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f206 0x3630e000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343d841c 0x3434b000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343d711a 0x3434b000 + 573722
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a4d6 0x3434b000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a39e 0x3434b000 + 62366
6   GraphicsServices                0x30bdefc6 0x30bdb000 + 16326
7   UIKit                           0x377db73c 0x377aa000 + 202556
8   MyApp                       0x000024de main (main.m:14)
9   MyApp                       0x0000249c start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f3b4 0x3630e000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x37039e78 0x3702d000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x37039b96 0x3702d000 + 52118

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f010 0x3630e000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f206 0x3630e000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343d841c 0x3434b000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343d7154 0x3434b000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a4d6 0x3434b000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a39e 0x3434b000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x3682e128 0x36786000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aac16 0x3319b000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aaad0 0x3319b000 + 64208

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3631f068 0x3630e000 + 69736
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aaf2e 0x3319b000 + 65326
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aacaa 0x3319b000 + 64682
3   CoreMedia                       0x32306000 0x32303000 + 12288
4   MediaToolbox                    0x35169fba 0x35166000 + 16314
5   CoreMedia                       0x32325bc6 0x32303000 + 142278
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aac16 0x3319b000 + 64534
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aaad0 0x3319b000 + 64208

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f010 0x3630e000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3630f206 0x3630e000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x343d841c 0x3434b000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x343d7154 0x3434b000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a4d6 0x3434b000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3435a39e 0x3434b000 + 62366
6   Foundation                      0x35d5abc2 0x35d4a000 + 68546
7   Foundation                      0x35d5aa8a 0x35d4a000 + 68234
8   Foundation                      0x35dee59a 0x35d4a000 + 673178
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aac16 0x3319b000 + 64534
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aaad0 0x3319b000 + 64208

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3631f570 0x3630e000 + 71024
1   CoreFoundation                  0x343dc66a 0x3434b000 + 595562
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aac16 0x3319b000 + 64534
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x331aaad0 0x3319b000 + 64208

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1
```

Comment: Here's a post from someone else that encountered the same error.  Does it help at all? http://purushukla.blogspot.com/2011/10/application-has-active-assertions.html

Answer (score 0):

`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` has a time limit that you may be exceeding.  You can see how much time is remaning with `UIApplication`'s `backgroundTimeRemaining` property.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on ending your background task when the app returns to the foreground via applicationWillEnterForeground().  iOS only allows 3 mins to perform work in the background.  This is why the background task begin method has an expiration handler.  You should cleanup up your task (very quickly) and end that task (via endBackgroundTask) when the expiration handler is called:

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bkgndTask;
---
bkgndTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    if (bkgndTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] bkgndTask];
        bkgndTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}];
```